# Performing data transportations in RxJS with Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, reactive-programming

I'm using RxJS 5.0.0-alpha.12 to perform some data transformations, and some of those transformations use Promises.

```
return observable
.flatMap(item => {
  return Observable.zip(

    Observable.fromPromise(fs.readFile('./config.json')),

    Observable.of(item),

    (s1, s2) => {
      return {
        config: JSON.parse(s1.toString()),
        testResult: s2
      };
    }
  );
})
.flatMap(item => {
  return Observable.zip(

    Observable.fromPromise(
      getStudentIdFromStudentNumber(item.testResult['Student Primary ID'])
    ),

    Observable.of(item),

    (s1, s2) => {
      return {
        'Test Date': s2.config.testConstants.ROGL_Begin_Year.testDate,
        'Student Id': s1,
        'Student Number': s2.testResult['Student Primary ID'],
        'Grade Level': s2.testResult.Grade,
        'Composite Score Alpha': s2.testResult['Composite Score']
      };
    }
  );

});
```

Note that both `fs.readFile` (`fs` here being the name given to [fs-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise)) and `getStudentIdFromStudentNumber` return a Promise.

It seems like having to `zip` the original `item` that is getting emitted from `observable` with the results of each Promise is cumbersome. Is there a cleaner way to use the results of these two Promises with this Observable?

What makes this tricky (to me) is sometimes the Promise relies on a field within the `item` object emitted by `observable` (eg., `getStudentIdFromStudentNumber`), and other Promises may not rely on `item` (eg., `fs.readFile`).

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (twice) using `Observable.of(item)`, this is redundant as `item` is already in scope.
Also, you can call both promises in parallel. `zip` is perfect for exactly that.

If you want to make transformations to an item before you use it, put a `map` inside the `zip`. For example, we can extract the `testDate` early.

While we're on it, we can use meaningfull variable names.

If you have more than 2 promises, zip will happily accept 3, 4 or more arguments.

Lastly we use `flatMap` around the zip to flatten the stream of `zip` observables back to items.

```
return observable
  .flatMap(item => {
    return Observable.zip(
      Observable.fromPromise(fs.readFile('./config.json'))
      .map(config => JSON.parse(config.toString().testConstants.ROGL_Begin_Year.testDate))
      , Observable.fromPromise(
        getStudentIdFromStudentNumber(item.testResult['Student Primary ID'])
      ), (testDate, id) => {
        return {
          'Test Date': testDate,
          'Student Id': id,
          'Student Number': item['Student Primary ID'],
          'Grade Level': item.Grade,
          'Composite Score Alpha': item['Composite Score']
        };
      }
    )
  });
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but I think it's missing a `return` before `Observable.zip`

Comment: AH right, i usually use the `(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression` syntax, used return for clarity here, and then forgot one :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be more inclined to map with the flatMap to have my results flow through.

Something like the following, might do what you're looking for.

```
return observable
  .flatMap(item => Observable.fromPromise(fs.readFile('./config.json'))
    .map(file => ({ config: JSON.parse(file.toString()), testResult: item })))
  .flatMap(({ config, testResult }) => Observable.fromPromise(getStudentIdFromStudentNumber(item.testResult['Student Primary ID']))
    .map(id => ({
      'Test Date': config.testConstants.ROGL_Begin_Year.testDate,
      'Student Id': id,
      'Student Number': testResult['Student Primary ID'],
      'Grade Level': testResult.Grade,
      'Composite Score Alpha': testResult['Composite Score']
    })));
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you elaborate  a little on why a flatMap would be more advantageous to the OP?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the scope of the `flatMap` to your advantage. Since you have to create an `Observable` from the promises, you can just return that directly. However, you still want to use the `item` in each `flatMap`, so you can `map` the result of the `Observable` you created. I think code is clearer than words in this situation.

```
return observable
.flatMap(item => {
  return Observable.fromPromise(fs.readFile('./config.json'))
  .map(s1 => {
    return {
      config: JSON.parse(s1.toString()),
      testResult: item
    };
  });
})
.flatMap(item => {
  return Observable.fromPromise(
    getStudentIdFromStudentNumber(item.testResult['Student Primary ID'])
  )
  .map(s1 => {
    return {
      'Test Date': item.config.testConstants.ROGL_Begin_Year.testDate,
      'Student Id': s1,
      'Student Number': item.testResult['Student Primary ID'],
      'Grade Level': item.testResult.Grade,
      'Composite Score Alpha': item.testResult['Composite Score']
    };
  });
});
```